# Why am I getting an array of NANs when trying to plot a map with D3.js?

Tags: svg, maps, d3.js, gis, geojson

I am tring to plot a map with d3.js using GeoJSON, but the paths generated look like this:

```
<path d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,‌​NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,N‌​aNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,Na‌​NLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN‌​LNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL‌​NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLN‌​aN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZ">
```

the code and data are in this Gist:
https://gist.github.com/4157853

I can load the data just fine on QGIS.

Does any one know what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have specified the offset in the Mercator projection doesn't seem right. The projection.translate method expects a two element array:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-mercator_translate

So instead of:

```
proj.translate(-43.8,-23.2).scale(10);
```

you would need to say:

```
proj.translate([-43.8,-23.2]).scale(10);
```

-- edit --

See source of projection.translate: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/3.0/src/geo/projection.js#L139

```
  projection.translate = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return [x, y];
    x = +_[0];
    y = +_[1];
    return reset();
  };
```

If the argument `_` is not an array then `+_[0]` will return a `NaN` and therefore the `x` and `y` will become `NaN`s. (This is because trying to get one element from a number (e.g. 213[0]) returns `undefined` and casting `undefined` to a number (e.g. +undefined) yields `NaN`.)

Comment: Why doesn't it explain the NaN's? The projection function takes part in translating the GeoJSON structure to a path string; so if it is configured wrong it will have an effect on the path string. What happened when you changed the offset argument to a 2-element array? When I took your code and made those changes, it produced valid paths; in your case it didn't?

Comment: See more detailed info in the edited answer why you see NaN's in the string.

Comment: Sorry, fixing the translate arguments did produce valid paths, but they are still invisible. @nautat , Did you manage to make the map visible? I hope I am closer now but still thing that this error should produce an Exception, and maps should have an autocenter() methos on d3.js

Answer (score -1):

If the code you posted in the gist is everything you're trying to run, then the data you show in `data.json` is not being loaded anywhere.  Anyway, your `draw` function is acting on the data defined by the variable `map` (line 16), which refers to a `simulation` variable which isn't set anywhere.  And even if it did, line 34 then refers to a `features` property of the object passed in as json, which `map` does not have.

In summary, you need to pass the JSON you posted in the gist to your draw function.  Then it might well work.  If you don't pass in valid data to the d3 SVG helpers, you'll get a bunch of `NaN` out.

Comment: That is not the whole thing, obviously. This is part of web app and if you look closely you will see that there is is a template marker where the JSON is inserted. I have modified the gist and added the final generated HTML, so that you can inspect the JSON.

Comment: To further squash any doubts, I can inspect the variable *map* in firebug and see that it is in fact being interpreted into an object with the expected structure.